# Merge Rows to one ID with values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Good Day,

I am still learning about SQL and its query structure but I am having difficulty with the following:

I have a table with Id’s and times, some registrations have more than one ID and each ID has its own datetime stamp.
I am trying to build a query where I am only trying to get the single registration back with either one ID or both linked to the registration.

Here is the table structure:

```
Registration    ID      DATETIME            IDType
Reg1            1001    16/07/2014 16:48    SFR
Reg1            1002    14/07/2014 12:04    TFR
Reg2            1004    16/07/2014 16:54    SFR
Reg2            1005    17/07/2014 09:16    TFR
Reg3            1006    14/07/2014 15:24    SFR
Reg4            1007    14/07/2014 14:27    SFR
Reg4            1008    14/07/2014 14:27    TFR
Reg5            1009    14/07/2014 13:00    SFR
Reg5            1010    17/07/2014 09:16    TFR
Reg6            1011    16/07/2014 16:48    SFR
```

Here is the data structure i am getting back with my query:

```
Registration    IDS     DATETIMES           IDT     DATETIMET
Reg1            NULL    NULL                1001    16/07/2014 16:48
Reg1            1002    14/07/2014 12:04    NULL    NULL
Reg2            NULL    NULL                1004    16/07/2014 16:54
Reg2            1005    17/07/2014 09:16    NULL    NULL
Reg3            1006    14/07/2014 15:24    NULL    NULL
Reg4            NULL    NULL                1007    14/07/2014 14:27
Reg4            1008    14/07/2014 14:27    NULL    NULL
Reg5            NULL    NULL                1009    14/07/2014 13:00
Reg5            1010    17/07/2014 09:16    NULL    NULL
Reg6            1011    16/07/2014 16:48    NULL    NULL
```

What I would like to achieve is the following:

```
Registration    IDS     DATETIMES           IDT     DATETIMET
Reg1            1002    14/07/2014 12:04    1001    16/07/2014 16:48
Reg2            1005    17/07/2014 09:16    1004    16/07/2014 16:54
Reg3            1006    14/07/2014 15:24    NULL    NULL
Reg4            1008    14/07/2014 14:27    1007    14/07/2014 14:27
Reg5            1010    17/07/2014 09:16    1009    14/07/2014 13:00
Reg6            1011    16/07/2014 16:48    NULL    NULL
```

HERE IS THE QUERY:

```
SELECT 
       UI.[Registration] 
      ,UI.Unit_ID AS MSTRACKUNITIDTWO
      ,CASE UI.[IDType]
        WHEN 'SFR' THEN UI.[ID]
       END AS IDS
      ,CASE UI.[IDType]
        WHEN 'SFR' THEN UI.[DATETIME]
       END AS DATETIMES
      ,CASE UI.[IDType]
        WHEN 'TFR' THEN UI.[ID]
       END AS IDT
      ,CASE UI.[IDType]
        WHEN 'TFR' THEN UI.[DATETIME]
       END AS DATETIMET
  FROM [InfoFleetSQL_PULS].[dbo].[UnitInfo] AS UI
```

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using - SQL Server?

Comment: added `sql-server` tag based on the non-standard `[..]` "quoting"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For readability you can treat your one table as if it were two; one with sfr data, one with tfr data:

```
select
  sfr.[Registration],
  sfr.[ID] as ids,
  sfr.[DATETIME] as datetimes,
  tfr.[ID] as idt,
  tfr.[DATETIME] as datetimet
from      (SELECT * FROM [UnitInfo] WHERE [IDType] = 'SFR') as sfr
left join (SELECT * FROM [UnitInfo] WHERE [IDType] = 'TFR') as tfr
  on sfr.[Registration] = tfr.[Registration];
```

This is not the fastest solution, but makes it very clear what the query is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use an aggregation and combine the values using `MIN()` or MAX()`:

```
SELECT UI.[Registration], 
       MAX(UI.Unit_ID) AS MSTRACKUNITIDTWO
       MAX(CASE UI.[IDType] WHEN 'SFR' THEN UI.[ID] END) AS IDS,
       MAX(CASE UI.[IDType] WHEN 'SFR' THEN UI.[DATETIME] END) AS DATETIMES,
       MAX(CASE UI.[IDType] WHEN 'TFR' THEN UI.[ID] END) AS IDT,
       MAX(CASE UI.[IDType] WHEN 'TFR' THEN UI.[DATETIME] END) AS DATETIMET
FROM [InfoFleetSQL_PULS].[dbo].[UnitInfo] AS UI
GROUP BY UI.[Registration];
```